# How to combine loop result in dart

Tags: android, flutter, dart

Hello i have a simple for loop what i want to combine the loop results into 1 string separated with a comma

```
   String loc;
   for(var q=0; q<2; q++){
       userData = res;
       loc = userData[q]['location']; 
       print(loc); //value in first loop is location A value in first second loop is location B i want to combine them on 1 string
      }
```

Comment: simply append values to loc.

Comment: loc= loc+userData[q]['location];

Comment: You want to combine like appending string  or create a new array of location?

Comment: [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(157)] Unhandled Exception: NoSuchMethodError: The method '+' was called on null.

Comment: use String loc="";

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want just append in String then

```
void main() {
  String loc="";
  List<String> locs = ["a","d","B","C"];
   for(var q=0; q<2; q++){
       loc = (loc.length>0? (loc+", ") : loc)+ (locs[q] ?? " "); 
      }

print(loc); 
}
```

Comment: [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(157)] Unhandled Exception: NoSuchMethodError: The method '+' was called on null.

Comment: thank you but how could move the separator from the 1st to the last in my case i use comma  Example ,Location A into Location A,

Comment: edited thank you i figured it out now , i just use this code   loc = (userData[q]['location'] ?? " - ")+","+loc;

Comment: hello i have small problem in "Location C,"  how to remove the last comma it should be like this "Location A, Location B" not this "Location A, Location B,"

Answer (score 1):

The traditional way would be to collect the strings into a string buffer, and manually add the comma:

```dart
var buffer = StringBuffer();
String separator = ""; // Avoid leading comma.
for (var data in userData) {
  buffer..write(separator)..write(data["location"]);
  separator = ",";
}
var loc = buffer.toString();
```

Another approach is to collect the values into a list and then use the `join` method:

```dart
var loc = [for (var data in userData) data["location"]].join(",");
```

That's probably more convenient in most cases, except when you need to do fancy computation on each element.

I have avoided using the `for(;;)` loop since you don't actually use the index for anything except accessing the user data. Then it's better to just `for`/`in` over the list elements directly.

Answer (score 0):

Try ForEach

```
 void main() {
 List<String> places = ['New York', 'London', 'Berlin'];
 String linearPlace = '';
 places.forEach((thePlace) {
 linearPlace = linearPlace + thePlace + ", ";
 });
 print(linearPlace);
 //output:   New York, London, Berlin, 
 
 //   In case of Map
 Map<String, String> countryCapitalsMap = {'Austria': 'Vienna', 
 'Armenia': 'Yerevan', 'India': 'Delhi'};
   
 String countryWithCap = '';

   countryCapitalsMap.forEach((key, value) {
   countryWithCap = countryWithCap + key + ': ' + value + "\n";
   });
    print(countryWithCap);
 // output:
 // Austria: Vienna
 // Armenia: Yerevan
 // India: Delhi
```

}